# better_player stop working after add video_trimmer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exoplayer

Better_Player worked before adding Video_Trimmer, but after I added Video_Trimmer, it stopped playing the video, and if I remove Video_Trimmer again, Better_Player works.

Things I tested:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling the application
2. Using lower versions of Better_Player

```yaml
better_player: ^0.0.83
video_trimmer: ^1.1.3
```

console error is:

```
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557): java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:186)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:430)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8273)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
E/flutter (18557): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior., null, java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
E/flutter (18557):  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:186)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:430)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
E/flutter (18557):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/flutter (18557):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/flutter (18557):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/flutter (18557):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (18557):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter (18557):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (18557):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/flutter (18557):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/flutter (18557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8273)
E/flutter (18557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
E/flutter (18557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
E/flutter (18557): )
E/flutter (18557): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (18557): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (18557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18557): #2      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.setDataSource (package:better_player/src/video_player/method_channel_video_player.dart:118:5)
E/flutter (18557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18557): #3      VideoPlayerController._setDataSource (package:better_player/src/video_player/video_player.dart:408:5)
E/flutter (18557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18557): #4      BetterPlayerController._setupDataSource (package:better_player/src/core/better_player_controller.dart:485:9)
E/flutter (18557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18557): #5      BetterPlayerController.setupDataSource (package:better_player/src/core/better_player_controller.dart:274:5)
E/flutter (18557): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18557): 
W/System  (18557): A resource failed to call close. 
I/BufferQueueProducer(18557): [SurfaceView[com.example.meetbin/com.example.meetbin.MainActivity]#5(BLAST Consumer)5](id:487d00000006,api:1,p:18557,c:18557) disconnect: api 1
I/BufferQueueProducer(18557): [SurfaceView[com.example.meetbin/com.example.meetbin.MainActivity]#5(BLAST Consumer)5](id:487d00000006,api:0,p:-1,c:18557) disconnect: api -1
I/BufferQueueProducer(18557): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#4(BLAST Consumer)4](id:487d00000005,api:1,p:18557,c:18557) disconnect: api 1
I/BLASTBufferQueue(18557): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#4] destructor()
I/BufferQueueConsumer(18557): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#4(BLAST Consumer)4](id:487d00000005,api:0,p:-1,c:18557) disconnect
D/DecorView[](18557): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
```

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: When you try to play the video is there any error in the console?

Comment: yes error is:

E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557): Failed to handle method call E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557): java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior. E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(18557): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)

Comment: @EstebanMuñoz
i edit answer and added full console error

Comment: Hi, did you find anything , I am facing the same issue @dwalves

Comment: no finally i use chewie player instead of better_player @ChetanKhanna

Answer (score 4):

i was facing the same issue now fixed by following this  [#1085](https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer/pull/1085)

to fix this just use this better_player version :

replace

```
better_player: ^0.0.83
```

by

```
better_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/tintran-dev/betterplayer.git
```

also make sure you have added the formatType for m3u8 and mdp

```
BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
    BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
    "url",
    videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.hls,
    drmConfiguration: BetterPlayerDrmConfiguration(
        drmType: BetterPlayerDrmType.token,
        token: "Bearer=token",
    ),
);
```